# Citrix Client Fails To Establish A Connection

Tags: session, citrix

Users on one server can't establish an in-session Citrix-connection. The user starts a desktop from the local Citrix Presentation Server 4.5 farm. In this session the user connects to a remote Citrix farm (version unknown) via a Citrix web interface. He is able to log in and the available programs are shown. After clicking on a program ICA-client starts saying "Connecting to xxx". After the progressbar is filled the window disappears and nothing happens anymore. Not even an error-message is shown.

On another server with the same user-credentials it works fine. After "Connecting to xxx" the next progress bar shows (checking user credentials, running logon script etc.) and then the session is ready. But I can't find the difference between the servers. Has someone any experience with such a behaviour and maybe a solution or workaround for it?

Facts & Figures

- Citrix Presentation Server 4.5
- Rolluppack 4
- Citrix Hotfix PSE450R04W2K3029
- Windows Server 2003 SP2 (32bit)
- ICA-Client (on server) 10.00.52110 (automaticly installed with PS4.5)

I hate to say this: Updating the software and operating system is no option.

Thanks for your help.